# Proper Cordova developing environment in VS Community 2015

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

After having spent some hours trying to figure this out I'm surrendering and hope someone here can help me.

**Problem**

I doesn't get any IntelliSense suggestions for Bootstrap classes

**This is what I've tried**

I'm about to develop a Cordova-based app with Bootstrap. While looking at numerous guides and examples I started off by creating a new project, a blank Cordova project. I added jquery and bootstrap under dependencies in bower.json and those packages was downloaded. As stated in a guide at taco.visualstudio.com I then manually copied the js, css and font files into appropriate folders under "www". Finally I added links to these files inside my index.html.

The thing is that I have another web app0 project, a ASP.NET project that was developed at my work. They use Bootstrap and when I work with that project I get IntelliSense suggestions for Bootstrap classes while typing

That makes me wonder that my problem may have something to do with my working environment? That I have to do something else in order for Visual Studio to recognize what libraries I use and read those CSS files and come up with suggestions?

Comment: Is this a TypeScript project?

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying. I've forwarded this post to the JavaScript team for investigation. Thanks for reporting it. (disclosure: I work for Microsoft)

Comment: Does the IntelliSense work in one of the sample projects on the http://taco.visualstudio.com site?

Comment: Well, since all CSS classes defined in site.css have been used in index.html I can't really tell. Thing is, if I use a Bootstrap class, say col-md-1, once in a html file, IntelliSense picks that one up. I've tried both minified and regular versions of CSS filed

Comment: I should add that IntelliSense for UnderscoreJS works like a charm, it gives me proper suggestions on functions and such.

Comment: @MichaelBraude, any word from the JS team? I've been trying all sorts of things but I still can't get it to work.

I can also add that none of my custom classes in Site.css is working with IntelliSense either :-/

Comment: @PaulvanBrenk works on the JS team :) Thanks for pinging us.

Comment: I'm not sure what IntelliSense you're not seeing... can you give a code sample

Comment: In, for example, index.html I don't see any IntelliSense when writing something like <div class="col where I expect to get all the classes from Bootstrap (that I use in this particular project) that starts with col. As I mentioned I get it when working in a ASP.NET project but not Cordova project

Comment: Actually, just start a blank JavaScript Cordova project. Define a custom class in Site.css and try to use it in index.html. You should get your custom class in a list of suggestions, but you will not.

Comment: @PaulvanBrenk, have you guys found any solution for this?

Comment: Hi All , I am facing this problem now . Any Solution ?

Comment: @MichaelBraude Any good news for that problem ? I am now having this same problem .

Comment: As Paul mentioned, we need a code sample to go further. Can you try upgrading to VS 2017?